# Este query de AdventureWorks debe devolver la fecha (mes y año) y monto total de las ventas, pero regresa vacio

Tags: sql-server, sql

este query que se volvera reporte de Report Builder se describe como sigue: El reporte recibe como parámetro de entrada el Año del cual se quieren saber las ventas y devuelve una tabla con los montos totales de las ventas de cada mes de dicho Año y cuantas ordenes se vendieron en el mes.

```
--use [AdventureWorks2017]
--go

Select OrderDate, LineTotal
From [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] SOH join sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
on SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.LineTotal
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, me regresa dos columnas vacias, que debo hacer? gracias adelantadas.

Comment: Esta sintaxis es SQL server no?

Comment: no se si responde a tu pregunta esto, pero si añadiste alias a las tablas, en tu SELECT tambien referencia las columnas con dichas alias  Select SOH.OrderDate, SOD.LineTotal, por ejemplo

Comment: ademas creo que tu condicion en on SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.LineTotal, LineTotal no corresponde al ID de la otra tabla o si?

Comment: Si @BetaM SQL Server.

Comment: Correcto edite por qué habías puesto MySQL

Comment: Tu join esta mal,  SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.LineTotal busca el campo en la tablet SOD que haga referencia al ID de la tabla SOH

Comment: Si @Rodrihgo que la relacion tenia que ser **ON SOH.SalesOrderId = SOD.SalesOrderId**

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select OrderDate, LineTotal
From [AdventureWorks2017].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] SOH join sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD
on SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID`
```

Comment: Agrega la explicación de los id en el  `join` para que te marquen como respuesta correcta. 

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo esta consulta responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: y eso que hace?